How to add a fullscreen button to the ApexCharts toolbar
I'm using ApexCharts to create charts in a Vue.js project.
I want to customize the toolbar menu to include a viewFullscreen option. The goal is to add a button in the chart's toolbar that allows the user to toggle fullscreen mode.

However, I don't see any built-in support for viewFullscreen in the ApexCharts Docs for toolbar options. Is there a way to extend or customize the toolbar menu to add this feature?

The docs pretty clearly show that you can use customIcons to add your own icons. And via the click property you can assign a function, that will make your desired target element go into fullscreen. (If you don't know how to do the latter, please do a bit of research.)

@C3roe, thank you! I did it

In ApexCharts, you can add custom icons to the toolbar and associate them with custom functionality. Since there is no built-in fullscreen button, I declared my own in the customIcons array like this:
customIcons: [{
  icon: '<img src="/static/icons/chart-carpet.png" width="20">',
  index: 4,
  title: 'Full Screen Mode',
  class: 'custom-icon',
  click: function () {
    const chartElement = document.getElementById('chart');
    if (!document.fullscreenElement) {
      chartElement.requestFullscreen();
    } else {
      document.exitFullscreen();
    }
  }
}]


How to use toolbar.customIcons[] - ApexCharts Docs

